# Organising large number of files into folders using R?

Tags: r, loops, wav, acoustics

Apologies for the simplicity of the question as I am a novice with R.

I have a large number of 1-minute audio files, with 1 minute recorded every 5 minutes. I need them organised by hour and saved to a new folder, so every 12 files need to be saved to a new folder. I have 7472 of these files so doing this manually would take too long.

Here is an example of the file names:

```
20210111_000500.wav,
20210111_001000.wav,
20210111_001500.wav,
20210111_002000.wav,
20210111_002500.wav,
20210111_003000.wav,
20210111_003500.wav,
20210111_004000.wav,
20210111_004500.wav,
20210111_005000.wav,
20210111_005500.wav,
```

which I want to all be in one folder, with the next hour starting as
`20210111_010000.wav` and so on.

How would I go about doing this?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You need to group them then copy them into the directory that you want

Comment: How would I go about doing this? What would the code be? Sorry I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: You said the code did not do anything. was there a folder called `my_folder` which was created?

Comment: Also does `nms` contain the names of the files you want to move?

Comment: no it doesn't, should I have entered the file names into the code somewhere?

Comment: No you should not. That means that the files are in a specific folder not in the working directory. try `nms <- list.files(path to your folder that contains the wav files, pattern = "\\.wav", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: In the global environment, nms says character (empty), is this correct?

Comment: No that is not correct. First where are the files stored? Now check the path to the folder in which the files are stored, and try running `list.files` to ensure that `nms` contains all the files that you need to rearrange. try `help(list.files)` in order to understand how to use the function

Comment: Okay, nms now contains all the elements. The issue was that the files are .WAV rather than .wav ... However, my new problem is that 'groups' is still a list of 0

Comment: what does  `strptime(nms, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")` give you?

Comment: strptime(nms, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") just returns NA for every entry

Comment: That is where the problem lies. Could  you try `strptime(basename(nms), "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")`

Comment: I did this and it grouped all the files from the first day into hours. However, I then ran the rest of the code and all the files have disappeared. Luckily I copied the files before I started so I still have them backed up.

Comment: Its not that they have disappeared. Check the folder called `my_folder` within your directory. All the files should be in there. But with respect to their groupings

Comment: There is no folder called `my_folder` , could it be because there are so many files and it takes some time to process? Also do I need to alter the code to account for the different days reflected in the file names?

Comment: I have editted the code. Try it out

Comment: This has taken the 12 files from the first hour of every day (total of 312 files) and put them together in a single folder named `hour_00` within `my_folder` . I also get the error message `Error in (function (x, y, folder = "my_folder")  : fl is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In dir.create(folder) :
 Error in (function (x, y, folder = "my_folder")  : fl is not TRUE`. How do I adjust it to get a separate folder for each hour of each day? Thank you for all your help by the way and sorry for my ineptitude.

Comment: well thats a step. So to get the files into each day, you will have to change the `groups` line have it as `groups <- split(nms, format(strptime(nms, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"),"%Y%m%d_hour_%H"))` instead

Comment: check the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along these lines. I first find all the .wav files, then define the folders, create the folders and finally move the .wav files to the new folders.

```
library(tidyverse)

setwd("path_where_wav_files_are_located_goes_here")

# a vector of paths to all .wav files in the specified directory
original_paths <- dir(pattern=".WAV$", full.names = T) %>% str_replace("\\.", getwd())
# only the file names
file_names <- dir(pattern=".WAV$")

# creating a data.frame with original paths and new paths where files are to be moved
df <- tibble(original_paths, file_names) %>%
  mutate(
    folder_name = (row_number() %/% 12 + 1) %>% paste0("_", .), # using integer division so that i have a dedicated folder for each 12 files
    new_path = paste0(getwd(), "/", folder_name, "/", file_names)
  )

# creating the directories
df$folder_name %>%
  unique() %>%
  paste0(getwd(), "/",  .) %>%
  map(
    ~dir.create(.x)
  )

# moving the files
walk2(df$original_paths, df$new_path, ~file.rename(.x, .y))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however when creating the directory, I get the error message: `Warning message:
In dir.create(.x) : 'E:\Audiomoth Files\Winter\Rural\Emma' already exists` , which is my folder with all of the files in it. What do I do here?

Comment: @HarHar I have edited my answer so that it accounts for the ".WAV" suffix rather then ".wav". You should check if the vectors/df contain the intended data before proceeding with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something in the lines of:

```
nms <- list.files(pattern = "\\.wav", full.names = TRUE)
groups <- split(nms, format(strptime(nms, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"),"%Y%m%d_hour_%H"))

f <- function(x, y, folder = "my_folder"){
  if(!die.exists(folder)){
      fl <- dir.create(folder)
      stopifnot(fl)
   }
  new_dir <- file.path(folder, y)
  if(!dir.exists(new_dir)) dir.create(new_dir)
  file.copy(x, file.path(new_dir, basename(x)))
  file.remove(x)
}

Map(f, groups, names(groups))
```

Comment: I've run this code and nothing seems to happen?